# Многомодульный war проект maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, config, модульность

Хочу научиться делать многомодульные проекты в maven, для этого создал следующую структуру проекта:

```
project
-pom.xml

-project-view
--pom.xml
--project-view-controller (Spring Controller)
---pom.xml
--project-view-web (Страницы Thymeleaf, css, js)
---pom.xml
---src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
---src/main/webapp/resources

-project-services
--pom.xml

-project-model
--pom.xml

-project-logic
--pom.xml

-project-parent
--pom.xml
```

В главном pom.xml, следующий код

```
<groupId>ru.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Project</name>

<modules>
    <module>project-view</module>
    <module>project-model</module>
    <module>project-services</module>
    <module>project-logic</module>
    <module>project-parent</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <finalName>Project name</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

В модуле project parent pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <!--Child modules-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-view</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-logic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Соотвественно в других pom просто стоят зависимости для каждого модуля и указаны parent.

Я хочу, чтобы можно было запаковать их всех в один war и деплоить в контейнер сервлетов или application сервер, чтобы в основном war-нике была папка WEB-INF/web.xml. В этой же папке все ресуры и thymeleaf шаблоны.

Spring должен находить и запускать все классы под аннотациями @Service, @Controller, @Repository

Также, чтобы в корне были содержимое папки resources, т.е. spring xml, application.properties и т. д. (Как при одном модуле maven)

Какая структура папок должны быть, может какие либо плагины maven нужны. Буду рад, если кто подскажет.

Comment: Небольшой совет. Не используете в вашем случае dependency management. Он не предназначен для того , что импортить артефакты. Он предназначен для того, чтобы контролировать версии зависимостей, которые вы добавите в проект, а так же их транзитивные зависимости.

Comment: Лучше не писать <artifactId> и <name> это только путает (особенно, того кто впервые видит проект), используйте первое.

Comment: Секция dependencyManagement должна быть только в родительском поме (project-name) и в ней перечисляются только артефакты твоего проекта. В модуле project-parent (имя не соответствует действительности, он совсем не парент, если смотреть на приведенную схему), все что ему нужно декларируется как dependency в dependencies. Ресурсы должны лежать в том модуле, где они используются, если одни ресурсы используются в нескольких модулях, то можно ресурсы также вынести в отдельный модуль.

Comment: А вообще, рекомендую заняться gradle, модули это совсем не про maven.